# How to allow websocket in iptable?

Tags: websocket, iptables

I've been searching the net how to allow websocket on iptbles, ive been developing on a local machine without websocket and now i have to deploy it on a machine having one. Can someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Websocket connections look like regular HTTP connections at the moment of connecting, so just allow that port and map it to the local IP address of the server with the websocket server.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/10/01/useful-iptables-port-forwarding-patterns/